# Android Paging 3 jetpack compose how to scroll to top or reset the paging when navigating back

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

I have been stuck on this for a while now. I have implemented Paging 3 with jetpack compose along with a remote mediator (Room Database) and its working fine. I just want to reset the paging and scroll to the top of the list when I navigate back to the screen of the paged list. animateToScroll(0) does not work it just scrolls the list on top of the current page. What I want is reset the entire list and start again like when its first opened.

Comment: Use LaunchedEffect(Unit) in main composable as "show screen trigger" and restart pager

Comment: but how do you do you reset the pager ? I am using this line     ```val allMovies = viewModel.getAllPopularMovies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()```

Comment: In viewmodel `var pageFlow by mutableStateOf<Flow<PagingData<Item>>>(flowOf())`. and, when needed, create new pager `val pager = Pager(....... pageFlow = pager.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`

Comment: But I don't know if the cache (`cachedIn(viewModelScope)` ) will be cleared

Comment: it worked thank you but the scroll does not focus on the first item of page 1 do you know whats going on? @vitidev

Comment: What is focus? Is this "selected"?

Comment: when i say Focus I mean the first visible item on the list should be the first item on page 1. yes it does load page 1 base on your solution but the scroll position is not reset.

Comment: use scroll like `animateToScroll(0)` )

Comment: I can't check, but i think in your case it's enough not to use `cachedIn` to make pager `forget` data and `state.scrollToItem(0)` to reset the position. I also think that to use `cachedIn` you need a separate scope

Comment: i want to retain the scroll position of the paged list sometimes so i needed the cachedIn. If i remove cachedIn sometimes the scroll position is not retained specially when the user navigates fast on the bottom navigation

Comment: `cachedIn` doc say "To avoid leaks, make sure to use a scope that is already managed (like a ViewModel scope) or manually cancel it when you don't need paging anymore". So I cache in child CoroutineScope and `cancel` previous.

Answer (score 0):

I now have the same need and I solved it like this.

```
@HiltViewModel
class IndexViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    ...

    var pageFlow by mutableStateOf<Flow<PagingData<Item>>>(flowOf())
        private set

    init {
        combine(section, sort, retry, ...) 
        { ... }
        .mapLatest {params->

            coroutineScope{
                val pager = Pager(...) {...}
            
                pageFlow = pager.flow.cachedIn(this)
            }

        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

or the same with `viewModelScope.launch` and `.collectLatest`

In theory, instead of a retry flow trigger, I need to use `LazyPagingItems.refresh()`, but it needs an additional scroll to the beginning, which in my case (LazyVerticalGrid) looks terrible